# How do I get sum of a column with different where conditions on the same table in rails?

Tags: sql, postgresql, rails-activerecord

I have method which calculates total income from `receipts` table. But currently it makes two `sql` calls every time the method is called, is it possible to improve the `sql` to make only one database call. I am fine with `raw sql` if needed.

```
  def total
    Receipt.where(receipt_type: 'income').sum(:amount) - Receipt.where(receipt_type: 'refund').sum(:amount)
  end
```

**Main objective is avoid two database calls. And if the difference can be calculated in the database only it will be even better. Thanks.**

Answer (score 1):

In SQL, I would solve this with

```sql
SELECT SUM(amount) FILTER (WHERE receipt_type = 'income')
       - SUM(amount) FILTER (WHERE receipt_type = 'refund')
FROM receipt
```

but I wasn't able to find the equivalent in ruby. I have no experience with it, but from [this example](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#retrieving-filtered-data-from-multiple-tables), I think the following should work:

```rb
Receipt.select("SUM(amount) FILTER (WHERE receipt_type = 'income') - SUM(amount) FILTER (WHERE receipt_type = 'refund') )
```

Comment: Amazing! and thanks for trying out the ruby version. I was missing the FILTER clause due to my basic sql knowlege.

Comment: This is a problem when refund or income records are absent, right?

Comment: No, if no records have `receipt_type` 'income', `SUM(amount)` simply returns 0